# I am unable to echo my JSON encode object containing values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am writing a script the will a echo a json object with values from the datatable when a request is sent to that script with a particular id, I have been able to get the records of member in an array but when I encode it into a json it become empty automatically but when I serialize the object and echo I will get all my record. I want the response in JSON.

```
<?php

include '../classes/RegisteredMemberDAO.php';

   if (isset($_GET['getMember'])) {
    $members =  RegisteredMemberDAO::getAllRegistedMember();
     //echo json_encode(RegisteredMemberDAO::getAllRegistedMember());

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
    $mysqli = db_connect();
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $members = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $member = new RegisteredMemberDAO();
       $member->setEmail($row['email']);
       $member->setSn($row['sn']);
      $member->setUsername($row['username']);
      $member->setPlan($row['plan']);
      array_push($members, $member);
    }
  $mysqli->close();
  //echo serialize($member);
  echo json_encode($members);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally this error happens if the result contains mixed encoding characters.

To fix it, use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` as second parameter to `json_encode` function.

```
echo json_encode($members, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

To check error occurred during `json_encode` put this code after json_encode.

```
echo json_last_error_msg(); // Print out the error if any
die(); // halt the script
```